# Angular : pipe used to transform value only for view but i want to override the value based on parameter value

Tags: angular, pipe, ngmodel

Angular pipe
Pipe is used to transform value only for view purpose

I have a use case where pipe is applied on a value , I am passing some parameters to pipe , based on which it is changing value .

What i want ,  i just dnt want to transform value for view , I want to override the old value with new value , based on parameters provided.

Is that possible??

Here after applying pipe on this.fldexcl.field2 , based on parameters , the value visible on HTML will change , but i want to override the value of property **this.fldexcl.field2**  based on parameters value change

````
<input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="this.fldexcl.field1" />


  {{this.fldexcl.field2|transformField2:this.fldexcl.field3:this.fldexcl.field4:this.fldexcl.field1"}}```
````

Answer (score 1):

A pipe takes in data as input and transforms it to a desired output.

Angular pipes, a way to write display-value transformations that you can declare in your HTML.

So you can't change value of variable using Pipe

Comment: Any Idea How can we achieve this scenario
where 
<input firstname>   <input [ngModel]="lastname | pipe:firstname" (ngModelChange)="invokefunction()" />  How can i invoke invokefunction()???